# sql where clause equals to true

Tags: java, where-clause

Here the `where a1.color= true` is not working in java. When I choose any color in dropdown list, there is error.

```
 //fist part
Public List<ConclusionBO> getConclusion(String color){
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("select something");
    sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
    //More statement
    if(transactionStatus.equals("all")) {
        query.setParameter("colorParam", true); 
    }else {
        query.setParameter("colorParam", color); 
    }
}
```

The code below when I do this way, it is working good for any color that I selected from the dropdown list. But when all is select from the drop down list, it shows no result (of course, because my database does not have value "all" for column color)

```
//second part
sql.append("select something");
sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
//More statement
query.setParameter("colorParam", color);
```

My problem here is that, I want to select all color(all record) from database when user select "all" from the dropdown list, that is why at first part I set `where a1.status = true`, because I want it to **return all result** but it ended up return error.

In the log the error message is:

> Not all named parameters have been set: [color]

I want to clarify that the //second part code is working just that it cannot show nothing when all is selected from drop down list because my database don't have "all" for color column.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround may be effective

> ```
> Public List<ConclusionBO> getConclusion(String color){
>     StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
>     sql.append("select something");
>     //More statement
>     if(!"all".equals(transactionStatus)) {
>         sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
>         query.setParameter("colorParam", color); 
>     } 
> }
> ```

With this you only add the *where* clause when there is something to filter by and if the selected option is *All* you just select every color.

Answer (score 0):

Add the WHERE statement only when you need to filter:

```
    Public List<ConclusionBO> getConclusion(String color){
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("select something");
        //More statement
        if(transactionStatus.equals("all")) {
            // do nothing
        }else {
            sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
            query.setParameter("colorParam", color); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your color column accepts strings. You cannot pass a boolean to it.
In my opinion you have two choises:

Either add a condition for when to append this:

```
sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
```

something like

```
if(condition for when only one color is neeed)) {
   sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
    }
```

no else required, because the alternative is 'all' when you do not want to filter the results.

OR

you can change the query from this

```
sql.append("where a1.color= :colorParam");
```

to something like this

```
sql.append("where a1.color IN (:colorParam)");
```

now instead of one color you can provide a list of colors.
And when you want to return all colors you just need to provide all the colors to the query.

```
String allcolors = 'Red, Green, Blue, etc' /* hardcode all your colors here or  better yet, dynamically populate them */

if(transactionStatus.equals("all")) {
        query.setParameter("colorParam", allcolors); 
    }else {
        query.setParameter("colorParam", color); 
    }
```